# What happens when playing a single Treasure Map?

Tags: dominion, dominion-seaside, dominion-hinterlands

I'm wondering if I can play a Scheme Card and then a Treasure Map and put the Treasure Map back on top of my deck at clean up.  But I can only put the Treasure Map back on top if it's in play and not trashed.

So if you play a single Treasure Map with a 2nd Treasure Map not in your hand, does it get trashed or does it only get trashed when you trash 2 Treasure Maps?

Comment: In general, you can answer questions by being really stubborn about trying to do what the cards say. More specifically, you do exactly what it says to do on the card, in the order it says it, and you do as much of it as you can. (In this case, you try to trash two, you can only trash one, and... there you are.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**,

The single Treasure map will get trashed first before you can Scheme it.  From the [Seaside rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_326_gameRules.pdf):

> **Treasure Map** - You can play this without another Treasure Map
>   in your hand; if you do, you trash this and gain nothing.

Scheme reads:

> At the start of Clean-up this turn, you may choose an Action card you have in play. If you discard it from play this turn, put it on your deck.

If the Treasure Map stays in your hand, it is not a valid target for Scheme.  If you play the single Treasure Map, it will trash itself before Scheme triggers at the start of Clean-up.